# How to avoid Softmax activation failure when using ReLU in hidden layers?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning

I'm training a my own implementation of an ANN with the MNIST dataset to identify numbers.

In other cases ReLU activation in the hidden layers has given me the best results for regression problems, however if I use softmax activation for the output layer together with ReLU in the hidden layers in a classification problem, softmax fails due to the high values obtained by ReLU, so I'm forced to use sigmoid or another bounded activation function.

I'm wondering if this is unavoidable or is there some technique I could use to avoid this?

Comment: You may want to try adding BatchNormalization layer after ReLU

Comment: What do you mean by "softmax fails"? Fails how? Can you expand your question to include the relevant code and data (like output values, unit activations)?

Comment: Yes, its not clear to me what you mean by "fails".

Comment: My softmax function in python is : 
def softmax(z):
   e = np.exp(z - np.max(z, axis=1, keepdims=True))
   return e / np.sum(e, axis=1, keepdims=True)
...what's happening is the values in z are too high which in turn results in a division by a very big number, so basically a division by infinity and softmax fails

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a native English speaker, I'm not sure what to call this problem

Comment: I have a similar issue, when I have a value such as 4000, e^4000 creates an extremely large number

Comment: When doing backward propagation, from the last layer (softmax) to previous layer (ReLU),   did you pass in one hot encoding of the output?

Comment: @CedricMartens Did you find a solution to this? I have no clue what I should do to change my ReLU from overflowing the weights.

Comment: @Antact I forgot how I fixed it but I remember it was something related to never needing to represent e^4000, either using properties of exponents or something similar. If you keep digging, you'll find